# How can I expose a view with date filter?

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I have a view and am listing a bunch of data from different content type .

What i need is , i have to list the data according to the date field given . That

is i have to filter the date in between two dates , Is this possible ?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

---

I used the exposed filter as follows :

[image]
[image]

The problem of this filter is  i have to manually enter the date in date field .
can i have data field which can select the date as in datepicker ?

Comment: you can see my answer in similar question if it suits you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225295/59051

Comment: Will it be possible to apply datepicker on **hook_views_query_alter** ?

Comment: Cannot say as i have not used it but believe it should be working in hook_views_query_alter(). For that, use datepicker in corresponding view and alter the view query inside the hook

Comment: Okay i applied **datepicker** to the field which right away solved my problem , as **Jquery Ui date picker** was readily available in D8

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yeah , i used the **jquery ui date picker** and applied to the data fields

Comment: do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and the solution I did was to add a date Picker to that `page` or `view` or `exposed form` and hide the current field in the twig file and add another with datepicker added to it

You can add a library to that view

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_views_view(array &$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['view'])) {
    if ($variables['view']->id() == "VIEW_ID") {
      if ($variables['view']->getDisplay()->display['id'] == "VIEW_DISPLAY_ID") {
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'YOUR_THEME_NAME/date-picker';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is explained in this answer: [How to configure an exposed filter in a view using a date picker?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200787/how-to-configure-an-exposed-filter-in-a-view-using-a-date-picker/259457#259457)

Answer (score 1):

In 7 you can do this with [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) by selecting the jQuery UI datepicker option in the screen of your screenshot. There is an alpha out for 8.

> The Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single-
>   or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively.
>   Description fields and Select All/None links can be added to exposed
>   filters to make for a better user experience.
>
> Views Filters is a powerful tool to refine the results returned by a
>   given view. When you expose a filter, you allow the user to interact
>   with the view making it easy to build a customized, advanced search.
>   For example, exposing the node type field as a filter lets your site
>   visitor limit their search queries to just blog entries. Better
>   Exposed Filters gives you greater control over the rendering of
>   exposed filters.

Comment: am úsing drupal 8

Comment: I know, so try the module for 8. It's alpha but actively developed.